# assign values to member of a struct with a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct

I have a struct of the form

```
struct Thing {

    std::vector<bool> A;
    std::vector<int> B;

};
```

in the main the struct is created inside a for loop and used as the input to a function

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
   Thing temporalthing;
   temporalthing.A=A;
   temporalthing.B=B;
   temporalresult=fun1(temporalthing,data)
 }
```

A and B are hardcoded into a series of vectors stored like this

```
std::vector<bool> A1{ 1,0,1};
std::vector<int> B1{ 2,1,3};
std::vector<bool> A2{ 0,1,1};
std::vector<int> B2{ 4,2,3}; ....
```

I want for each iteration of the for loop to take the corresponding value of A and B (loop 1 take A1 and B1, loop 2 take A2 and B2, ETC), if this were MATLAB this would be easy using reflection but I understand C++ does not have reflection, my other option would be to use a Switch Case structure of 50 different values that surely would work but I am not sure if this is the most optimal way to do it. Is there a better way?

I am new to C++ having a lot more experience with MATLAB but trying to learn... any help is very appreciated

Comment: How about a vector containing the `A1` etc. vectors? Then use `i` as an index into that vector?

Comment: You are not supposed to have variables `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and so on. Instead you are supposed to make a container (`std::vector`)  and use `A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]` and so on.

Comment: put your loop into a function where A and B are parameters and call it with appropriate pairs.

Comment: You can add two vectors vector<vector<int>> and vector<vector<bool>> to contain all A1,A2 etc and B1,B2 etc and assign like temporalthing.A = vecA[i]
temporalthing.B = vecB[i]

Comment: By the way, I think you meant "temporary", not "temporal".

Comment: thank you all...and sorry about my english, it is not my first language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

Change

```
temporalthing.A=A;
temporalthing.B=B;
```

to

```
temporalthing.A = getA(i);
temporalthing.B = getB(i);
```

The functions `getA()` and `getB()` can use whatever logic to return you an `A` and a `B` for the given `i`.

A simple implementation for `getA()` would be to store the various `A`s in a vector.

```
std::vector<int>& getA(size_t i)
{
   static std::vector<std::vector<int>> aList;
   if ( aList.empty() )
   {
      // Fill up the list
      aList[0] = {1, 0, 1};
      aList[1] = {0, 1, 1};
      // etc.
   }
   return aList[i];
}
```

Do the same thing for `getB()`.

---

If `getA()` can use `i` to compute the return value, then, it does not have to store the `A`s.

```
std::vector<int> getA(size_t i)
{
   int v1 = func1(i);
   int v2 = func2(i);
   int v3 = func3(i);
   return {v1, v2, v3};
}
```